# Is it safe to resize root partition?

Tags: partitioning, grub2, root, gparted, resize

My HDD is partitioned into two equal sized partitions. First is being used for Windows and Second for Ubuntu. Everything is working fine. But now I want to remove Windows and use the disk completely for Ubuntu. I can easily boot from live cd and use GParted to delete Windows partition and then expand Ubuntu partition to use the whole hard disk.

1. I want to know if its safe
2. Will resizing Ubuntu partition change any thing else like the partition UUID or any thing else?
3. Do I need to reinstall grub after resizing the root partition?

It would be great if some one who has already done this can give their advice here.

Answer (score 8):

> I want to know if its safe

Generally, operations can fail. If operations on partitions fail, it can cause **data loss**, so be prepared and do **backups first**.

> Will resizing Ubuntu partition change [...] the partition UUID

No.

> Do I need to reinstall grub after resizing the root partition?

No.

It doesn't even matter if you've installed GRUB2 into the MBR (e.g., `/dev/sda`, default when installing Ubuntu), or into the root partition (e.g., `/dev/sda1`).

Comment: didnt work. The partition resized without error and had all the data but when I restarted the machine Ubuntu didnt boot. I then tried installing Grub to MBR. It installed okay but I guess wiped partition table as no partitions showed up after I restarted the machine after installing Grub. Gparted shows no partitions i.e unpartitioned empty drive.

Comment: That's both very weird. I'll try to reproduce this with a virtual machine. If you still have your disk untouched, you'll likely can recover the partitions. Boot with a live CD, download the 6.12-WIP version of [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download) (just extract and run, nothing to compile), and follow [these instructions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step#Partition_table_recovery) to rewrite the partition table.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I used GParted (live CD) to create a NTFS partition in the beginning (no time for installing Windows), installed Ubuntu 10.10 in the free space, used GParted (again from the live CD)  to delete the NTFS partition and resize the Ubuntu partition - after a restart Ubuntu booted just fine, using all the space on the disk. :-/

Comment: My windows partition was primary but Ubuntu partition was logical. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @binW: as long as you resized both, the extended partition and the logical one inside, everything should work fine. I again just tested this: http://img.xrmb2.net/images/199787.png - no UUID change, booted just fine.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can and the problem is with ubuntu being in a logical partition. just use testdisk write the partition table backup your data and install ubuntu with option to use the entire disk. that is it. i had the samr prob and solved it.