# Shrinking \root partition on SSD. How dangerous is this?

Tags: partitioning, root

In my first installation of Ubuntu I assigned 60 GB of my SSD to Ubuntu \root partition and afterwards I assigned some space in my HDD for \home and swap.

I had to do an Erase and Reinstall and I just noticed that my root partition now occupies my whole SSD.

I want to boot into Live Cd and use Gparted to shrink my \root partition but I am afraid that this may damage either the system or the SSD.

How dangerous is this procedure?

Comment: Not dangerous at all if you do it right.

Comment: And the right way is...?

Comment: You can easily repartition the hard drive again by reinstalling Ubuntu (assuming you have no data, which you want to backup if so). You can delete the existing partitions during installation and ubuntu will make a new partition table, or you can set them manually in the installer. This causes no physical damage to the hard drive.

Comment: I just shrunk root partition and everything seems to be fine. What's the best way to check the health of the system and of the ssd?

Comment: Related: [Is it safe to resize root partition?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21477/301745)

Comment: You should just not interrupt it while it is resizing. Any interruption might cause a corrupted partition.

Answer (score 0):

If the partition resizing worked, your system health is probably as good as it was before the operation.

To check the health of an SSD, run `smartctl`. For example, if your SSD is device /dev/sda, run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` command. The output will contain a "SMART overall-health self-assessment test result" which is almost always "PASSED" but if "FAILED" is a sure indicator of failure. More detail and indications of problems can be found in the attributes table. Below is an example from a failed SanDisk SDD. Note the non-zero RAW VALUE for Reallocated_Sector_Ct (not good) and Reported_Uncorrect (bad). Different drives support different attributes but you can focus on attributes that contain the words error or fail. You can then run the extended offline test with the `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` command. Wait for the prescribed length of time for the test to complete and then run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` again. In the example below, the device had a "read failure" result so there was definitely a problem.

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 4
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       34
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   253   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       288
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       22
166 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1
167 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       40
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       5658
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       212
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       22
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4646
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       8
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       56434
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   072   028   ---    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 17/28)
212 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
230 Head_Amplitude          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       39510
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   004    Pre-fail  Always       -       99
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       603966
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       454942
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   253   253   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       376644
243 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       00%       288         14416944
```

Comment: Does smartctl work with UUID? Because he is not recognizing the name of my SSD (when I do smartctl --all /dev/sda e gives me a report of my HDD.. but my SSD does not seem to have sda in the name and does not appear . My SSD is nvme

Comment: Actually I just read that nvme is not supported in smartctl

Comment: Here: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/02/09/using-nvme-command-line-tools-to-check-nvme-flash-health/