# Can I flash Ubuntu to a partition of a 32 GB SD card?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, sd-card

I have Ubuntu Server 21.04 installed on a 32 GB SD card. I am booting it in a Raspberry Pi.

I would like to swap out Ubuntu Server for Ubuntu Mate.

I read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/855039/can-ubuntu-be-installed-to-the-pendrive-it-was-booted-from?noredirect=1#comment1316572_855039) that you could boot to RAM and then write the OS to the SD card.

However, could I also just boot normally, and partition the SD card I am currently using, and flash a second Ubuntu to that partition, then delete the first partition? How so?

Comment: You have enough room(?) on your target partition to just do a regular install.

Comment: @ubfan1 You can't perform a regular install in Raspberry Pi, you need to flash the SD card

Comment: What's the difference between a regular installation and flashing an SD card?

Comment: You can not resize a mounted root partition, You can not unmount a root partition that is in use. That is the reason for toram boot. You can flash a Live install to SD Card and you can also flash a Full install to SD Card.  For difference between Full install and Live install see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1353289/43926.

Comment: So the answer is "no", not because I am using an SD card, but just because it's always impossible to allocate space for the partition from within the pre-existing partition, if the pre-existing partition is already taking up the whole disk.

Comment: Shrink the root:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/948468/shrinking-root-partition-on-ssd-how-dangerous-is-this   then install: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-desktop-on-raspberry-pi-4#1-overview (or the server specific link near the top).